# Как сделать замену нечетных и четных символов в строке?

Tags: c#

> [image: Задание]

Как найти все индексы символа в строке, потом найти четное нечетное вхождение этого символа и соответсвенно заменить каждое нечетное вхождение символа на '<', а четное на '>'.

Comment: Что то сами пытались?

Comment: Да. Одако преподаватель сказал что StringBuilder сказал что мы не изучали. И в итоге я в тупике. Прикладываю какой код был: https://pp.userapi.com/c850324/v850324922/1652fa/WSvGabmUr2E.jpg

Comment: Перебрать строку как массив чаров, и сравнивать каждый индекс заменяя сам символ

Comment: но в вашем коде вы не всю задачу решаете. У вас в том коде на выходе будут только `<` и `>`, так?

Comment: ну да. Но надо чтоб он заменял только '!' нечетный на <, а четный >
Незнаю как это сделать(

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц строка immutable-тип, просто так вы не замените символ в строке. Нужно перед посимвольным перебором преобразовать строку в массив `char[]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ксли нельзя использовать StringBuilder, то можно попробовать массив. Например так

```
private string Replace(string inp, char c)
{
    var holder = new char[inp.Length];

    int counter = 1;
    for(int i=0; i<inp.Length; i++)
    {
        if (inp[i]!=c)
        {
            holder[i] = inp[i];
            continue;
        }

        if (counter%2==0)       
            holder[i] = '>';
        else        
            holder[i] = '<';

        counter++;
    }

    return new string(holder);
}
```

Проверка

```
Console.WriteLine(Replace("123!456!789!", '!'));
```

Вывод

```
123<456>789<
```

Comment: https://pp.userapi.com/c850324/v850324107/169708/IY1QAwEr7Qc.jpg 
Что я не так делаю?

Comment: @Muereta копипастите неверно `new string(holder);`

Comment: Спасибо огромное

Comment: @Muereta пожалуйста. Если вы выбираете этот ответ как решение, поставьте ему галочку.

Answer (score 2):

немного LINQ:

```
private void Do(string inputStringParam)
{
    var enumerable = inputStringParam.Select((c, i) =>
    {
        if (c != '!') return c;
        var isOdd = i / 2 == 1;
        return isOdd ? '<' : '>';
    });
    var newString = new string(enumerable.ToArray());
}
```

если нужно "считать" символы не по номеру строки, а по номеру вхождения '!':

```
private void Do(string inputStringParam)
{
    var i = 0;
    var enumerable = inputStringParam.Select(c =>
    {
        if (c != '!') return c;
        i++;
        var isOdd = i / 2 == 1;
        return isOdd ? '<' : '>';
    });
    var newString = new string(enumerable.ToArray());
}
```

или `string.Concat(enumerable);`? - не уверен что это лучше

Comment: `var isOdd = i / 2 == 1;` тут наверное должен быть остаток от деления.